# How to restore database from .bak file (database backup) in wix installer 3.9

Tags: sql-server, wix, windows-installer, wix3

I am trying to restore sql server database from .bak file(database backup file) using wix installer 3.9. But Unfortunately its not happening. Here is my trial codes

```
<Fragment>
    <Binary Id="PHRBackupBin" SourceFile="Database/PHR.bak"></Binary>    

    <!--<util:User Id="SQLUserSA" Name="[DB_USER]" Password="[DB_PASSWORD]"></util:User>-->
    <util:User Id="SQLUserSA" Name="sa" Password="sa"></util:User>

<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <Component Id="SqlComponent" Guid="8A1C82DB-1DD3-4FB5-8600-4F370FE1E04B">
      <Condition>NOT Installed</Condition>
      <sql:SqlDatabase Id="SqlServerDatabase" Database="PHR" Server="." CreateOnInstall="yes" DropOnUninstall="yes" User="SQLUserSA" ContinueOnError="no" Instance="SQLEXPRESS">          
      <sql:SqlScript Id="PHRBackup" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="PHRBackupBin" ContinueOnError="no" />
    </sql:SqlDatabase>
    <CreateFolder/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>

<ComponentGroup Id="DatabaseConfiguration">
  <ComponentRef Id="SqlComponent"></ComponentRef>
</ComponentGroup>
```

The above installer runs successfully if I replace the file with **.sql(sql script) file**. I also tried writing a script file to restore the database but no luck. May I ask the community how to run a .bak file from the wix installer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you try the custom cation to perform to restored the data base ?
 1) add the custom action, pass the back file location and inside the custom action write C# code to restored data base on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to restore it using the bak file. This is not a script (which is required for the sql:SqlScript component), this is a backup file which is different.

A .bak file is usually the native backup file created in SQL Server.

A .sql file is a script, and could even be a mySQL dump which when run would seem like a restore although technically it would be creating a new db.

This is confirmed in the wix documentation: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/sql/sqlscript.html